# make my menu stay at the top of the browser except on mobile devices (i.e #header below 400px)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make my menu stay at the top of the browser except on mobile devices (i.e #header below 400px), this is my code which isn't throwing up any errors when i check is JSHint, but at the same time isn't working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#header').width() > 400) {
            $("#menu").sticky({
                topSpacing: 0
            });
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(main);
```

Could really use some help if anyone has an idea?

Comment: Question is not very clear, can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $("header") instead of $("#header")?

Comment: You could do this in css using media queries instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('#header').css('width') > 400) {
    $("#menu").sticky({
      topSpacing: 0
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You should take a look at media queries

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, got it working now, the correct code was

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if($(window).width() > 450){
         $("#main").sticky({topSpacing:0});
     }
   });
```

Here's the fiddle for an example

http://jsfiddle.net/n8L301jb/6/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS solution. You can use `@media (min-width: 400px)` to specify certain rules that only apply when the window width is 400 or greater.

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
    #menu {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/bqv8c6vz/).